# jQuery: closest / parent not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, css-selectors, closest

I have a basic HTML table with a button in each row. 
By click on the button I want to alert the text from the second TD in the same TR.

For some reason the below does not work and either returns nothing or null (depending on whether I try .text() or .html() ). parent instead of closest failed as well.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ? 
(My table has the ID "myTable" and all TRs are in a TBODY, if needed.)

**Example TR:**

```
<tr><td style="width:30%"><strong>Row 1:</strong></td><td id="fldRow1" style="width:60%">test text</td><td><button type="button" id="copyRow1" onclick="copyOutput()">Copy</button></td></tr>
```

**JS function:**

```
function copyOutput() {
    var output = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    alert(output);
}
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, why are you using inline events?

Comment: Thanks. Could I achieve this also using JavaScript only ? I do need the inline events in this case.

Comment: Well jQuery is JavaScript so you are already using JavaScript only. And no you would not need the inline events in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`this`](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)in you code not refer to the current element it refers to the window object.

**HTML**

Change

```
onclick="copyOutput()"
```

to

```
onclick="copyOutput(this)" //pass refer of the current element
```

---

**js**

```
function copyOutput(el) { //el get current element clicked
    var output = $(el).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    alert(output);
}
```

Comment: Perfect - that works ! Thanks for the quick help. Will accept as soon as I can.